# OS kill android service and never restart it again

Tags: android, service, locationmanager

I have created an app which have the functionality to track user location in every minutes and
 send those on server(Tracking is based on 24*7*365). But I am facing problem like some time OS kill the service and never restart again.
I am using this code given bellow.

```
public class DisplaySystem extends Service implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

}

public static UpdateAddressThread updateAddressThread;
public final String NAMESPACE = CommonUtilities.APP_NAMESPACE;
public final String URL = CommonUtilities.APP_URL;
private static final String TAG = "@@@@@@@DisplaySystem@@@@@@@@@@";
private static String imei;
static Context context;
long minTime = 50 * 1000l;
float minDistance = 50.0f;
private static Timer timer;
String mythred;
// static String data_cursor;
static String myAddress;
double dist;

boolean on_start;
static final String URLD = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?";
static final String KEY_ITEM = "element"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "status";
private static Location location1;
private static long milisec_gps;
public static String chaseforceLogMessage = "<---Service messages-->";
static ArrayList<String> rowIdList = new ArrayList<String>();

public float getPrv_lat() {
    // if (ChaseForce.D) Log.d("DisplaySyste","getPrv_lat");
    return PreferenceData.getTempString(context, "prv_lat");
    // return prv_lat;
}

public void setPrv_lat(float lastLat) {
    PreferenceData.setLocData(context, "prv_lat", lastLat);

}

public float getPrv_long() {
    return PreferenceData.getTempString(context, "prv_long");
        }

public void setPrv_long(float lastLong) {
    PreferenceData.setLocData(context, "prv_long", lastLong);
}

public static Location getLocation1() {
    return location1;
}

public static void setLocation1(Location location1) {
    DisplaySystem.location1 = location1;
}


// private static float[] results;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

// public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.Demo";
// static Intent intent1;
// A request to connect to Location Services
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private LocationClient mLocationClient;

SharedPreferences mPrefs;

SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;


boolean mUpdatesRequested = true;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    context = getApplicationContext();

}

@SuppressLint("Wakelock")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int arg1, int arg2) {

    System.out.println("SERVICE STARTED-->");

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ChaseForce.WritePrifrence1("user_first_login", true);
    ChaseForce.WritePrifrence1("service_start", false);

    if (ChaseForce.D)
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    // imei = "1234567890123";
    imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval((Long.parseLong(ChaseForce
            .ReadPrifrence("Location_update_interval")) * 1000) + 1000);

    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval((Long.parseLong(ChaseForce
            .ReadPrifrence("Location_update_interval")) * 1000) + 1000);

    mUpdatesRequested = true;

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(
            adm.enterprises.chaseforce.LocationUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    // //////////////////////////////////////////
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    timer = new Timer();

    on_start = true;
    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("OnDuty", true) != false) {

            on_start = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("OnDuty");
        } else {
            on_start = false;
        }

    } else {
        on_start = true;
    }

    if (servicesConnected()) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    toCallAsynchronousGetUpdate();

    Thread obj1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            do {
                Log.e("INSIDE ", "DO METHOD");

                sendLocationOnServer(mythred);
                /* wakeScreen(); */

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            } while (true);

        }
    });

    if (!obj1.isAlive()) {
        obj1.start();

    }

    super.onStartCommand(intent, arg1, arg2);
    return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
}


public void onLowMemory() {

    super.onLowMemory();

}

public static void toCallAsynchronousGetUpdate() {
    System.out.println("local cloud@@@ ");
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTaskGetUpdate;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    doAsynchronousTaskGetUpdate = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (ChaseForce.D)
                        Log.e("Cloud_Local", "toCallAsynchronousGetUpdate");

                    try {
                        GetUpdateTask getUpdateTask = new GetUpdateTask(
                                context);
                        getUpdateTask
                                .execute(new String[] { "local_cloud" });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTaskGetUpdate, 2 * 60 * 1000,
            1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);// execute
        }

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void sendLocationOnServer(String my_thred_nmae) {

    System.out.println("send location onserver method");
    try {

        Database smsDatabase = new Database(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = smsDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("LOCATION", new String[] { "rowid",
                "Latitude", "Longitude", "KM", "IEMI", "DateTime",
                "milliseconds", "Battery_Level", "Gps_Status", "Address",
                "CurrentKm" }, null, null, null, null, "milliseconds");
        String locationData = "";
        String Lastmili = new String();
        double Lat = 0.0;
        double Long = 0.0;

        if (ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("location_data").equals("")
                || ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("location_data").equals(null)) {

            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                rowIdList.clear();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int i = 0;
                double km = 0.0;
                do {

                    locationData += fetchDataFromCursor(cursor);
                    System.out.println("cursor data-->" + locationData);

                    Lastmili = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("milliseconds"));
                    Lat = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("Latitude")));
                    Long = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("Longitude")));

                    System.out.println("Rowid value--->"
                            + cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex("rowid")));
                    rowIdList.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("rowid")));
                    if (ChaseForce.D)
                        Log.d("DisplaySyste", "cursor.moveToNext()" + i);
                    i++;
                } while (cursor.moveToNext() && i < 10);

                ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("location_data", locationData);

                int j = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < DisplaySystem.rowIdList.size(); k++) {
                    j += db.delete("LOCATION", "rowid = ?",
                            new String[] { DisplaySystem.rowIdList.get(k) });
                }

                System.out.println("Number of Rows deleted::--> " + j);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Do nothing!!!!");
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("milisec", Lastmili);
        if (ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("location_data").equals("")
                || ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("location_data").equals(null)) {
            // ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("location_data", locationData);
            Log.e("Location data", "Empty");
            /*
             * String ThredException =
             * "Location data is empty beacuse OnLocationChange() not working"
             * ; logPrint(ThredException);
             */
        } else {
            String dataLocation = ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("location_data");
            /*
             * String dataLocation = my_thred_nmae + "  " +
             * String.valueOf(ChaseForce.packetId++) + "#" +
             * ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("location_data");
             */
            ConThread conThread1 = new ConThread(3, dataLocation, Lastmili,
                    context);
            conThread1.start();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("FORCE CLOSE REASON--->");
    }
}

public static String fetchDataFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String lat, lon, km, imei, datetime, battlevel, gpsstatus, address, currentkm;
    String data_cursor = "";
    lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Latitude"));
    lon = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Longitude"));
    km = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("KM"));
    imei = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("IEMI"));
    datetime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DateTime"));
    battlevel = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Battery_Level"));
    gpsstatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Gps_Status"));

    System.out.println("DATA-->" + lat + lon + km + imei + datetime
            + battlevel + gpsstatus);
    address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Address"));
    System.out.println("DATA-->" + lat + lon + km + imei + datetime
            + battlevel + gpsstatus + address);

    if (address.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        /*
         * String ThredException =
         * "Null adress found when net is disconnected!!" +
         * String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
         * DisplaySystem.logPrint(ThredException);
         */
        System.out.println("Adress after fettng null--->" + address);
        address = getAddressFromWeb(Double.parseDouble(lat),
                Double.parseDouble(lon));

    }
    System.out.println("Adress after fettng --->" + address);
    currentkm = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CurrentKm"));

    data_cursor = (new String(lat + "~" + lon + "~" + km + "~" + imei + "~"
            + datetime + "~" + battlevel + "~" + gpsstatus + "~" + address
            + "~" + currentkm + "~" + ","));
    return data_cursor;

}

public static String getAddressFromWeb(double latitude, double longitude) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myAddress = "null";
    System.out.println("<---MY CODE IS  WORKING NOW--->");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String TAG_CONTACTS = "results";

    String address = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
            "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
                    + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=false&time"
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + latitude, longitude);

    System.out.println("fetching path : " + address);
    // Creating JSON Parser instance

    try {
        System.out.println("INSIDE TRY-->");
        JSONArray results = null;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        JSONArray Allcontacts = null;
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(context);
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(address);

        String json_status = json.getString("status");
        System.out.println("after ststus" + " " + json.getString("status"));
        if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {

            results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            JSONObject c = results.getJSONObject(0);
            String strReturnedAddress = c.getString("formatted_address");
            myAddress = strReturnedAddress.toString().replace(",", " ");

            ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("JournyAdd", myAddress);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Insert value-->" + myAddress + "STATUS "
                    + json_status);
            return myAddress + "STATUS " + json_status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("My exception-->" + e.getMessage());

        myAddress = "null";
        return myAddress;

    }
    return myAddress;

}

public float getBatteryLevel() {
    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    if (ChaseForce.D)
        Log.d("Battary Level : ",
                String.valueOf(((float) level / (float) scale) * 100.0f));

    return ((float) level / (float) scale) * 100.0f;
}

private String GetBattryAlertString(String battry_level) {
    if (ChaseForce.D)
        System.out.println("battry_level : " + battry_level);
    String alert_string = new String();
    Time sys_time = new Time();
    sys_time.setToNow();
    String cur_time = String.valueOf(sys_time.hour)
            + String.valueOf(sys_time.minute);
    if (ChaseForce.D)
        System.out.println("cur_time: " + cur_time);
    Database smsDatabase = new Database(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = smsDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db
            .rawQuery(
                    "select * from ALERT where AlertName=? and FromTimeInterval<? and ToTimeInterval>?  and Status=?",
                    new String[] { "2", cur_time, cur_time, "0" });
    ArrayList<Alerts> arrayAlerts = new ArrayList<Alerts>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do {

            int AlertId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("AlertId"));
            String AlertName = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("AlertName"));
            String Alert_type = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Alert_type"));
            int Occerancetype = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Occerancetype"));
            String FromTimeInterval = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("FromTimeInterval"));
            String ToTimeInterval = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("ToTimeInterval"));
            String Threshold = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Threshold"));
            int Status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Status"));
            int CurrentStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("CurrentStatus"));
            String Mobile_No = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Mobile_No"));

            Alerts alert = new Alerts(AlertId, AlertName, Alert_type,
                    Occerancetype, FromTimeInterval, ToTimeInterval,
                    Threshold, Status, Mobile_No);
            if (ChaseForce.D)
                System.out.println("Battry Level "
                        + "Status: "
                        + Status
                        + "CurrentStatus : "
                        + (CurrentStatus == 0)
                        + "Occerancetype : "
                        + (Occerancetype == 0)
                        + "FromTimeInterval : "
                        + (Integer.parseInt(FromTimeInterval) < Integer
                                .parseInt(cur_time)));
            if (Integer.parseInt(Threshold) > Integer
                    .parseInt(battry_level)) {

                // if (alert.getOccerancetype() == 0) {
                // arrayAlerts.add(alert);
                // } else {
                if (CurrentStatus == 0) {
                    arrayAlerts.add(alert);
                }
                // }
            } else {
                if (CurrentStatus == 1) {
                    ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
                    updateValues.put("CurrentStatus", 0);
                    db.update("ALERT", updateValues, "AlertId=?",
                            new String[] { String.valueOf(AlertId) });
                }
            }
            // arrayAlerts.add(alert);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        alert_string = gson.toJson(arrayAlerts);
        if (ChaseForce.D)
            System.out.println("Battry alert_string: " + alert_string);
    } else {
        if (ChaseForce.D)
            System.out.println("Battry alert_string: null");
        alert_string = null;
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return alert_string;
}

/**
 * Verify that Google Play services is available before making a request.
 * 
 * @return true if Google Play services is available, otherwise false
 */
private boolean servicesConnected() {

    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        if (ChaseForce.D)
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG,
                    getString(R.string.play_services_available));

        // Continue
        return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
    } else {
        if (ChaseForce.D)
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, "Play Service is not available");
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startPeriodicUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("currentmilisec",
            Double.toString(location.getTime()));
    final Calendar ct1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    ct1.setTimeInMillis(location.getTime());
    int f_Year1 = ct1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int f_Month1 = ct1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int f_Day1 = ct1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    String from_date1 = String.format(f_Year1 + "/" + f_Month1 + "/"
            + f_Day1 + " " + ct1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
            + ct1.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + ct1.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    System.out.println("Gps Lat lng" + location.getLatitude() + ";"
            + location.getLongitude() + "Gps time-->" + from_date1);

    double km;

    if (location != null) {
        if (ChaseForce.D)
            Log.d("location Display System: ", location.toString());

        /*
         * intent1.putExtra("location", location);
         * 
         * sendBroadcast(intent1);
         */
        // /////////////////////////new ////////////////////
        if (getPrv_lat() != 0.0f && getPrv_long() != 0.0f) {
            double earthRadius = 6371.00;
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(location.getLatitude()
                    - getPrv_lat());
            double dLng = Math.toRadians(location.getLongitude()
                    - getPrv_long());
            double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                    + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getPrv_lat()))
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(location.getLatitude()))
                    * Math.sin(dLng / 2) * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            dist = earthRadius * c;

            Date d3 = new Date(location.getTime());
            Date d4 = new Date(ChaseForce.ReadLongPriference("MIliGps"));

            System.out.println("Calculating distance date" + d3 + "-->"
                    + d4);
            if ((dist >= 0.3 && (location.getTime() - ChaseForce
                    .ReadLongPriference("MIliGps")) > (Long
                    .parseLong(ChaseForce
                            .ReadPrifrence("Location_update_interval")) * 1000) + 1000)
                    && (d3.compareTo(d4) > 0)) {

                km = (dist + ChaseForce.ReadFloatPrifrence("Km"));
                System.out.println("kilometer aftre adding--->" + km);
                ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("meterreading",
                        Double.toString(km));
                System.out.println("Metereeding Value--->"
                        + Double.toString(km));
                ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("Km", (float) km);

                setPrv_lat((float) location.getLatitude());
                setPrv_long((float) location.getLongitude());

            } else {
                km = ChaseForce.ReadFloatPrifrence("Km");

                System.out.println("Inside First Else Km-->" + km);
                ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("meterreading",
                        String.valueOf(km));

                /*
                 * ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("meterreading",
                 * ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("meterreading"));
                 */
                System.out.println("actual km2-->" + km);
            }
        } else {

            Log.d("DisplaySyste", "getPrv_lat()!=0.0&&getPrv_long()!=0.0");
            km = ChaseForce.ReadFloatPrifrence("Km");
            System.out.println("Inside Second Else Km-->" + km);
            /*
             * ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("meterreading",
             * ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("meterreading"));
             */

            ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("meterreading", String.valueOf(km));

            setPrv_lat((float) location.getLatitude());
            setPrv_long((float) location.getLongitude());
        }
        String from_date = null;
        Date d1 = new Date(location.getTime());
        Date d2 = new Date(ChaseForce.ReadLongPriference("MIliGps"));

        System.out.println("Date before inserting-->" + d1 + "-->" + d2);
        if ((d1.compareTo(d2) > 0)) {

            if (((location.getTime() - ChaseForce
                    .ReadLongPriference("MIliGps")) > (Long
                    .parseLong(ChaseForce
                            .ReadPrifrence("Location_update_interval")) * 1000) + 1000)) {

                System.out.println("<----Data Inserted Sucessfully--->");
                ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("MIliGps", location.getTime());
                Database smsDatabase = new Database(context);
                SQLiteDatabase db = smsDatabase.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
                insertValues.put("Latitude",
                        Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
                insertValues.put("Longitude",
                        Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

                insertValues.put("KM", km);

                insertValues.put("IEMI", ChaseForce.ReadPrifrence("ID"));
                insertValues.put("Battery_Level",
                        String.valueOf(getBatteryLevel()));
                final Calendar ct = Calendar.getInstance();
                ct.setTimeInMillis(location.getTime());
                int f_Year = ct.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int f_Month = ct.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                int f_Day = ct.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                from_date = String.format(f_Year + "/" + f_Month + "/"
                        + f_Day + " " + ct.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                        + ct.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                        + ct.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                insertValues.put("DateTime", from_date);

                LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    insertValues.put("Gps_Status", 0);
                } else {
                    insertValues.put("Gps_Status", 1);
                }

                String add_data = getAddressFromWeb(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());
                System.out.println("google api geocoder-->" + add_data);

                insertValues.put("Address", add_data);

                // srs code added
                System.out.println("Current km" + dist);
                insertValues.put("CurrentKm", dist);

                insertValues.put("milliseconds",
                        Long.toString(location.getTime()));

                if (db.isOpen()) {
                    db.insert("LOCATION", null, insertValues);
                    db.close();
                } else {
                    db.close();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Data is not inserted-->");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("TIME DOSENT EXCEDEED");
        }

        final Calendar ct2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        ct2.setTimeInMillis(location.getTime());
        int f_Year2 = ct2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int f_Month2 = ct2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int f_Day2 = ct2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String from_date2 = String
                .format(f_Year2 + "/" + f_Month2 + "/" + f_Day2 + " "
                        + ct2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                        + ct2.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                        + ct2.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        System.out.println("from date2" + from_date2);
        ChaseForce.WritePrifrence("DateTime", from_date2);

        generateNotification(context, "Location updated at " + from_date2);

        String a_string = GetBattryAlertString(String
                .valueOf((int) getBatteryLevel()));
        if (a_string != null && a_string.length() > 2) {

            SendAlertLowBattry sendAlertLowBattry = new SendAlertLowBattry(
                    context, new String[] { "SOS_Alert", imei, a_string });
            sendAlertLowBattry.start();

        }
    } else {
        if (ChaseForce.D)
            Log.d("DisplaySyste", "location is null");

    }

}

private void startPeriodicUpdates() {
    try {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        if (ChaseForce.D)
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException on connect");
        }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void stopPeriodicUpdates() {
    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CurrentStatus.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(5, notification);

}
```

}

Comment: Any error shown? LogCat output maybe? Don't use post all codes here.

Comment: Yes I reduces some code from this class because of limitation of words on stack overflow

Comment: I mean you should reduce to a minimum code example to illustrate the issue.

Comment: By the way, if you run this service THAT long then it makes sense that your service gets killed. Why not try being a little more battery efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a foreground service for it to be working all of the time. When the OS is low on resources it may kill background services, which may not start again. To ensure that the service is always running it will have to be started as a foreground service.

EDIT2:

> public final void startForeground (int id, Notification notification)
>
> Make this service run in the foreground, supplying the ongoing
>   notification to be shown to the user while in this state. By default
>   services are background, meaning that if the system needs to kill them
>   to reclaim more memory (such as to display a large page in a web
>   browser), they can be killed without too much harm. You can set this
>   flag if killing your service would be disruptive to the user, such as
>   if your service is performing background music playback, so the user
>   would notice if their music stopped playing.

for futher reading please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Please provide me code for how to start a service in foreground

Comment: I have removed my previous comment because I added an irrelevant peice of code. The correct way to implement this is to add the following line in the onStartCommand of the Service Class. startForeground(notificationId, notification); I have added the doc reference in EDIT2